# AWS Lambda handlers in Java, the package is unavailable

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, maven

I'm trying to implement an AWS Lambda handler in Java.
I use this dependency in my pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
    <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-lambda</artifactId>
    <version>1.11.487</version>
</dependency>
```

In my Java code:

```
import com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtimeContext;
import com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.RequestHandler;
import com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.events.APIGatewayProxyRequestEvent;
import com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.events.APIGatewayProxyResponseEven;
```

The IDE is complaining that there is no com.amazonaws.services.lambda package (and sub-packages). Tried the project re-import - no difference.

The full class names are taken from the AWS documentation here:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/java-programming-model-handler-types.html

I suspect that I use some wrong dependency. What Maven dependency is actually needed here?

Comment: See @JacobG's answer.  The library you want is not in the normal SDK.  You've included the *client* Lambda SDK in your `pom.xml`.  [This page](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/java-programming-model.html) does an ok job of explaining the libraries but it's not 100% clear.

Comment: Is it possible that Amazon AWS have changed their Java packages layout (especially the AWS Lambda library) and have not updated the documentation?

Comment: I added an answer that expands on the other ones.  Let me know if it answers your questions.

Comment: @stdunbar Answered below. Thanks for the great explanation. There is a strange problem with Maven dependencies. I've even tried to delete the entire local repo today, and it haven't changed the situation.

Answer (score 4):

The Java Lambda stuff is a bit confusing.  There is one library that you need to write a Lambda and an optional library to handle Amazon based events.

These libraries are somewhat documented on [this page](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/java-programming-model.html).

To use the **aws-lambda-java-core** library in maven you'll want to use:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
    <artifactId>aws-lambda-java-core</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.0</version>
</dependency>
```

as your Maven dependency.

To use **aws-lambda-java-events** (the Lambda events library) use the dependency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
    <artifactId>aws-lambda-java-events</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.5</version>
</dependency>
```

in your `pom.xml`.

In your example `com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.Context` and `com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.RequestHandler` come from the `aws-lambda-java-core` library.  **Your post looks like you have a copy/paste issue in the first import**.

But `com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.events.APIGatewayProxyRequestEvent` and `com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.events.APIGatewayProxyResponseEvent`  (again, your post has a typo in it) come from `aws-lambda-java-events`.  This library simplifies dealing with AWS events.  Your code looks like it wants to handle [API Gateway Proxy events](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/eventsources.html#eventsources-api-gateway-request).

Be warned, however, that by pulling in the `aws-lambda-java-events` library you pull in a huge number of AWS libraries.  For example, even if your Lambda only wants API Gateway events you'll still pull in a dependency on the S3 library as the events library also handles S3 events.  So your Lambda deployment package will be significantly bigger than if you don't pull that in.

As an alternative to the events library you can use something like [JsonPath](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath) to pull what you want out of the event.  Your Lambda would be something like:

```
import com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.Context;
import com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.RequestStreamHandler;
import com.jayway.jsonpath.JsonPath;

public class YourLambdaHandler implements RequestStreamHandler {
    public void handleRequest(InputStream inputStream, OutputStream outputStream, Context context) {
        String accountId = JsonPath.read(inputStream, "$.requestContext.accountId");
```

Which would read the `accountId` from the API Gateway event.

There is no question that this way is a bit more work but if you're only pulling a few items out of the event then it may be a lighter weight way to go.

**EDIT**

It looks like you have a build / IDE issue.  So, the smallest amount of code I can show is first a working `pom.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.yourpackage.handler</groupId>
    <artifactId>apigateway</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
            <artifactId>aws-lambda-java-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
            <artifactId>aws-lambda-java-events</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.5</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <createDependencyReducedPom>false</createDependencyReducedPom>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>shade</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

And a Lambda handler:

```
package com.yourpackage.handler;

import com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.Context;
import com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.RequestHandler;
import com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.events.APIGatewayProxyResponseEvent;

@SuppressWarnings("unused")
public class DemoHandler implements RequestHandler<APIGatewayProxyResponseEvent, String> {
    public String handleRequest(APIGatewayProxyResponseEvent apiGatewayProxyResponseEvent, Context context) {
        return "hello";
    }
}
```

Can you start with a new environment and try this out?

Comment: Thank you for the great explanation. However, my problem is more strange: the dependencies are in my local repository, - they were fetched successfully. The "com.amazonaws.services.lambda" package and its sub-packages are there, in the jar files - aws-lambda-java-*.jar (core, events). Despite of this, Maven build fails: "cannot find symbol" (the class APIGatewayProxyResponseEven in the package com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.events). What else could go wrong here?

Comment: @user3791111 - That's because it's `APIGatewayProxyResponseEvent` - you've missed the final `t` in the class name

Comment: Corrected the name. However, when I try to import anything beyond "com.amazonaws.services.lambda" it fails. In the IDE, I'm typing: "import com.amazonaws.services.", and the "lambda" is not there, like there in no library with this package (the jar is there, the classes are there, - Maven and IDE don't care).

Answer (score 1):

The following dependencies worked for me

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
        <artifactId>aws-lambda-java-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
        <artifactId>aws-lambda-java-events</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.6</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Answer (score -1):

Did you try the entire AWS SDK?

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.amazonaws/aws-java-sdk -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
    <artifactId>aws-java-sdk</artifactId>
    <version>1.11.489</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Tried the version 1.11.490 and it did not change the situation.